# Left join is giving unexpected results for columns which are not joined

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

I needed to find the records which are available in Table1 and not in Table2. For that, I wrote 2 queries:

```
select t1.a, t2.b, a.t1.c, t2.d, t2.e
from Table1 t1
left join Table2 t2
on t1.a = t2.d (and/where) t2.d is null;

select t1.a, t2.b, a.t1.c, t2.d, t2.e
from (select * from Table1) as t1
left join (select * from Table2) as t2
on t1.a = t2.d where t2.d is null;
```

The t2.d field is coming out to be NULL as expected. However, **t2.e** is giving not null values in first case, while it is giving null results (which is expected too) in second query.

Can you please explain the difference in behavior of the two queries?

Additional info: there is no null or blank in any data field. Using MySQL 5.6

Comment: What you describe does not seem possible, for either version of the query.

Comment: `(and/where)` is not valid syntax. What's the real first query?

Comment: Can you make a sqlfiddle with sample data that demonstrates the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    Table1
WHERE
    t1.a NOT IN
    (
        SELECT
            t2.d
        FROM
            Table2)
```

This will show you all records which are available in Table1 and not in Table2

Comment: I was actually trying to understand the difference between the results of 2 queries I had mentioned. I am not looking for solution. I was hoping to understand why non-joined fields of table2 are not giving null in one of the queries.